# Is it possible to find the close form solution of following Recurrence relation using sympy?

Tags: sympy

Example 1

```
F(0,t)=t
F(n+1,t)=F(n,2*t)
```

Example 2

```
F(0,y,t)=t
F(n+1,y,t)=F(n,y+1,t*y)
```

When I tried to manually solve above equation for close form solution and my findings are as follows(correct me if m wrong)

```
F(n,t)=2**n*t

F(n,y,t)=t*y*(y+1)*....*(y+n)
```

When I tried in sympy , I got the following results

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> F=Function('F')
>>> t=symbol('t')
>>> n=Symbol('n')
>>> f=F(n+1,t)-F(n,2*t)
>>> rsolve(f,F(n,t),{F(0,t):t})
t
>>> y=Symbol('y')
>>> f=F(n+1,y,t)-F(n,y+1,y*t)
>>> rsolve(f,F(n,y,t),{F(0,y,t):t})
t
```

Any other-way to get the expected result?

Looking forward for suggestion and correction ..

Comment: These wrong answers are bugs. I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11063.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsolve` in SymPy (as of 1.0) currently only supports linear recurrence relations, and in particular, functions of one variable only (see http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.recurr.rsolve).  I don't know if it's possible to solve this without SymPy implementing some more algorithms, other than using SymPy to help solve it by hand.

For the first one, you can solve it if you use the knowledge that `F(n, t) = G(n)*t`:

```
In [23]: f=F(n+1)*t-F(n)*2*t

In [24]: rsolve(f,F(n),{F(0):t})
Out[24]:
 n
2 ⋅t
```

It's not obvious to me how to do a similar thing with the second equation.